# Drop down menu in primefacess

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Using primefaces, how can i implement multiple selection of items in the dropdown list without using several dropdown menus...

is there tag  in primefaces??

Answer (score 1):

I think there's no primefaces component to achieve this but you can use plain jsf.

Try `<h:selectManyMenu>` or `<h:selectManyListbox>`.

Here is an example for the menu:

```
<h:selectManyMenu
    id="newsletters"
    value="#{bean.selectedItems}">
    <f:selectItems
        value="#{bean.availableItems}"/>
</h:selectManyMenu>
```

You'll find more information in the [Java EE tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnasi/index.html).

Comment: perfect and more as said in the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Primefaces 3.0 M1 has a SelectManyMenu component. You can download 3.0 M1 version [here](http://repository.prime.com.tr/org/primefaces/primefaces/3.0.M1/primefaces-3.0.M1-sources.jar)

2.2.1 doesn't have such component. Regards.